# Startapp new SDK 2.3.5

Tags: android, sdk, startapp

To comply with Google Advertising ID policy, Startapp requested their developers to update their apps with the new SDK 2.3.5.  While some of my apps could be updated successfully, those apps with webView failed to integrate with the new SDK. The problem is as follows:

- Sometimes, the Ad Splash screen hanged after 2 second loading.
- If the app could finally loaded, once I pressed the back button, the app froze, i.e. no response at all.  Here below are the codes:

  ```
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      StartAppSDK.init(this, "123456789", "123456789");

  StartAppAd.showSplash(this, savedInstanceState,
          new SplashConfig()
          .setTheme(SplashConfig.Theme.OCEAN)
          .setLogo(R.drawable.icon)
          .setAppName("Fun")
          .setOrientation(SplashConfig.Orientation.LANDSCAPE)
          );
  setContentView(R.layout.main);

  mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
  mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
  mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
  mWebView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
  mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/indexpage.swf");

  startAppAd.showAd(); // show the ad
  startAppAd.loadAd(); // load the next ad
  StartAppAd.showSlider(this);


  }




  @Override
  public void onResume(){
  super.onResume();


  startAppAd.onResume();

  }

  @Override

  public void onBackPressed() { 



      startAppAd.onBackPressed();

      super.onBackPressed();


  }



  @Override

  public void onPause() { 

      mWebView.stopLoading(); 
      mWebView.loadUrl("");
       mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/indexpage.swf");


      super.onPause();


  }
  @Override
  public void onReceiveAd(Ad ad) {
  }
  @Override
  public void onFailedToReceiveAd(Ad ad) {
  }


  }
  ```

Comment: Angela, can you please explain me in detail, that what you need actually?

Comment: Pratik, I would like to clarify that with the new SDK integration, my app failed to load splash ad right after loading the splash screen (not in webview).  When I pressed the back button, it has no response, i.e. not displaying exit ad.  However, when I turned off the phone screen, the exit ad appeared after 15 min.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the following calls in the `onCreate()` method are unnecessary:

```
startAppAd.showAd(); // show the ad
startAppAd.loadAd(); // load the next ad
```

And they actually better be removed, as the call to `StartAppAd.showSplash()` handles the loading and displaying of the splash screen and the splash ad.

In order to further assist you, please contact our support team at support@startapp.com, or through the support section in our developers portal, and provide the following details:

1. For the first problem - is it the splash screen that hangs or the splash ad? (the splash screen is the screen with your app's name and icon, the splash ad is the ad that comes after the splash screen).
2. For the second problem - please try to remove your code from the `onPause()` method and see if the app still freezes.
3. Please provide your app's APK for us to be able to check the problems you mentioned.

Thanks

Comment: Miki, thanks for your reply.  I did report to Startapp support team and is now pending their reply.  I posted my question here because I thought there might also someone face the same problem.